# ICC profile buffer addition to JPG buffer

Tags: jpeg, exif, icc, libexif

I have a txt file with icc profile data. Also I have image which is not having icc profile. I am able to extract EXIF information for the image.

Now how can I apply ICC profile to image loaded in buffer. I have to do this with libexif library in C++.

I tried other approaches but they are applying whole exif information to the jpg.

Comment: ICC has nothing to do with Exif. Judging from "_have to do this with_" keep in mind that nobody here wants to do tasks you are paid for originally. Also code excerpts showing your effort are always welcome, as well as proper punctuation (question mark ending a question).